# f.lux doen't start after booting

Tags: startup-applications, f.lux

I've installed f.lux some time ago and also had it in my startup apps. But now, all of a sudden, it doesn't startup automaticall anymore. I have the command "fluxgui" in my startup applications. If I open it from console, it works without a problem. Can I somehow debug, why the program was not auto started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same issue.

Changing the `Exec` field in `~/.config/autostart/fluxgui.desktop` to `sh -c "fluxgui >> ~/logflux.txt 2>&1"` would allow you to examine the reason for the failure to start-up.

I've got the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 381, in <module>
    app = Fluxgui()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.indicator = Indicator(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 149, in __init__
    self.setup_indicator()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 162, in setup_indicator
    'gtk-icon-theme-name')
ValueError: could not find setting
```

Apparently, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet/issues/3). However, a [workaround](https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet/issues/3#issuecomment-31337026) is provided by `@sricks`:

> This bug is still present. BUT you can fix it by modifying line 162 of
>   `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py`.
>
> Change the `theme =` line
>   to look like `theme = 'ubuntu-mono-dark'`. If you don't have that theme
>   installed, no problem, it just uses a default. Lines `161`, `162`, and `163`
>   should look like this:
>
> ```
> if gtk.gdk.screen_get_default():
>     theme = 'ubunto-mono-dark'
>     if theme == 'ubuntu-mono-dark':
> ```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found for me another solution: I just removed flux and installed redshift instead, which works perfectly.