# f.lux stopped working kernel upgrade

Tags: f.lux

I recently upgraded to the **4.4.0-53-generic** kernel, and now [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com) is not working. I have it launching on startup, but now it simply is not changing the temperature color settings:

Here is the output of launching `fluxgui` :

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py:162: GtkWarning: Cannot transform xsetting Net/IconThemeName of type gchararray to type GdkColor

  'gtk-icon-theme-name')
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py:162: Warning: g_value_unset: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed
  'gtk-icon-theme-name')
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py:162: GtkWarning: Cannot transform xsetting Net/IconThemeName of type gchararray to type gint

  'gtk-icon-theme-name')
```

After thinking the error was simply to do with these GTK related issues I resolved this by modifying line 162 of:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py.
```

as described in [THIS ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/a/621788/25737) for a similar problem, however this did not get F.lux back up & running. The next thing for me to do was open f.lux up with a terminal with:

```
fluxgui
```

and then clicking on the applet indicator and choosing 'preferences'. The output in the terminal is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 99, in open_preferences
    self.get_colortemp()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py", line 90, in get_colortemp
    index = self.xflux.expect("Color.*")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1418, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1433, in expect_list
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1521, in expect_loop
    raise EOF(str(err) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7f5926029850>
version: 3.1
command: /usr/bin/xflux
args: ['/usr/bin/xflux', '-l', '49.2827\xc2\xb0 N', '-k', '4200', '-nofork']
searcher: <pexpect.searcher_re object at 0x7f5926029890>
buffer (last 100 chars): ''
before (last 100 chars): ' only support 24/32-bit displays right now.\r\nXF86VidModeGetGammaRampSize returned 2048 entries.\r\nc\r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: 255
flag_eof: True
pid: 6363
child_fd: 4
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: <open file '/tmp/fluxlog.txt', mode 'w' at 0x7f592995aae0>
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

After getting nowhere I decided to reinstall Flux, which seems to give me access to the preferences pane which wasn't working before reinstall, however nothings happens when I change my location or even preview, which both used to work.

Running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshift/Flux/brightness-controller Stopped Working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/817508/redshift-flux-brightness-controller-stopped-working). TLDR: kernel changes, file a bug in Launchpad.

Comment: flux works for me on 4.4.0-51, -53 and -57. Have you tried 4.4.0-57?